# Why the implicit cursor go into infinite loop?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a stored PL/SQL function ListCustomerOrder in Oracle which take in parameter of the customer number. The function will find all the orders made by a customer. It must return a string of characters that contains all the customer's order number. All customer's order separated by commas (,). If a customer does not make any order, then just list the customer's number and name. The customer number and customer name appear once and follow by order number.

Eg.

```
44708 Jack: 864355
41900 May: 4515, 493894, 664641
44988 Tom:
```

I want to print customer key and customer name once. Then I print order key until there is no value in cursor qRow but doesn't seen to work. It just go into infinity loop, print the 3 attributes infinity. I'm using implicit cursor.

This is my code:

```
create or replace function ListCustomerOrders (test NUMBER) return varchar2 is 
    prev_key CUSTOMER.C_CUSTKEY%type := 0;    
    emptyList varchar2(32767):='';
    popList varchar2(32767):='';     

begin
FOR qRow in (select C_CUSTKEY, C_NAME, O_ORDERKEY from ORDERS join CUSTOMER on O_CUSTKEY =   C_CUSTKEY where C_CUSTKEY = test)

loop
    if prev_key != qRow.C_CUSTKEY then
        emptyList := (to_char(qRow.C_CUSTKEY) || ' ' || to_char(qRow.C_NAME) ||' : ' );
    end if;


    if qRow.O_ORDERKEY is not null then
       popList := ((to_char(qRow.O_ORDERKEY)) || ', ');
    end if;

    emptyList := emptyList || popList;

    prev_Key := qRow.C_CUSTKEY;

    popList := '';

end loop;

return emptyList;

end ListCustomerOrders;
/
SHOW ERRORS
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use a cursor, try a select using listagg() and group by e.g:

```
SELECT
       C_CUSTKEY
    ,  C_NAME
    ,  LISTAGG(O_ORDERKEY, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY O_ORDERKEY) AS Orders
FROM CUSTOMER 
JOIN ORDERS ON O_CUSTKEY = C_CUSTKEY
WHERE C_CUSTKEY = test
GROUP BY
      C_CUSTKEY
    , C_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If the list will always be under 4KB in length, use `LISTAGG` as Adrian's answer shows. You can prepend (`||`) the key and name columns to the orders string to get the single string in the format you are asking for.
2. If you must exceed 4KB and require PL/SQL, the method you are using requires an `ORDER BY C_CUSTKEY` in your cursor or the `prev_key` logic won't work.
3. A small point, but your code would be cleaner if you omitted `popList` entirely and assigned the new piece directly to `emptyList`.
4. The point is evidently to return a nested table of results (many customer rows, with their nested order list represented non-relationally as a delimited string). But you are returning only the last customer. If you are calling this from another PL/SQL routine you will need to assign each customer to a collection and return the collection at the end, or if you are calling it in SQL you can make it a pipelined function and pipe each finished string as you complete each customer (though this last option would require the use of SQL types and that limits your string to 4KB, in which case `LISTAGG` is superior).
5. Lastly, think carefully about whether this is the right approach. A delimited string is a non-relational structure that is hard to work with in a relational database. There are very few justifiable reasons for assembling multiple pieces of data into one compound-value.